# Notification format FCM firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I test a push notification fcm with a postman. When i put my data by

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

I receive a notification. But when i change it to a custom notification

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Sending Notification Body From Data",
     "title": "Notification Title from Data",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

I don't receive any notifications anymore. Anyone knows this problem ?
I follow this article https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3

My thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this from your second statement, which is required:

```
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
```